# Androidx error creating new flutter project in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

When I want to start a new Flutter Project in Android Studio (3.5.1.) I get the following event:

> Error creating project. Could not find an option named "androidx". 
>   Empty folders are created, but no project.

I've not set anything to needing androidx and I've updated everything I could in Android Studio.

How do I get around this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, update the Gradle version in `build.gradle` file in the root of android folder to `3.5.1`.

Then update test dependencies in `build.gradle` file in the `android/app/` directory to androidx as follws.

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
```

And update `distributionUrl` in `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

Comment: My pleasure @denelan

Answer (score 25):

There's an accepted answer already but to me the way to solve that was very different, so I still post it hoping for it to be useful to someone.

In my case, I just had to update flutter. To do so, I ran

```
flutter upgrade
```

from the command line.
That took a few minutes. Afterwards I was able to create a Flutter project from Android Studio flawlessly.

Comment: flutter upgrade can result in a crash, but despite that the project was created successfully...??? Now there is a head scratcher.

Answer (score 3):

Due to no upgrade for a long while, I need to upgrade the flutter by running the following command in terminal:

```
flutter upgrade --force
```

Comment: `--force` option is not available for all flutter versions. If someone comes here with an old flutter version, try without `--force` flag

Answer (score 2):

Download a newver version of Flutter SDK from [the Flutter official website](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install) and replace the old version on your hard drive with it. I worked for me.

Comment: If you are like me and coming from version 1.0, `flutter upgrade` won't work, it doesn't even recognize the `--force` option. This is the best way forward, worked perfectly.

Comment: flutter upgrade didn't work for me. This did, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Download a newer version of Flutter SDK from https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install and replace the old version on your hard drive with it. I worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

On Android Studio 4.0, try to create a new flutter project. And then install the new flutter SDK. It should fix this issue.

Comment: Just letting you know, in the question it referring to the Android Studio 3.5.1. Would it still work?